# How to force Visual Studio to *really* stop execution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This is odd:  I have something of a kluge of an app in VS (2012) -- SignalR, Linq, and a few other things stirred together.

The app can be running and I press STOP (the solid square), then the "Start debug" arrow, and the app partly starts over, but part of it *continues where it left off*.  (I have a C# method that is receiving events and counting, and the count keeps increasing from where it was, not from the start.)

Pressing "restart" is the same -- the app flips around a bit and continues incrementing from where it was.

The only way I've fount to force it to reset is to kill and restart VS (or end and restart the project).

So, does anyone know of a better way to actually stop and restart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you mentioned SignalR, I'm going to assume that this is a web application. In that case all the stop button does is to stop debugging. The app is still in a running state. Rebuilding the app will usually force IIS to unload it. If that doesn't work, you can reset IIS by opening a command prompt and typing:

```
iisreset
```

Comment: Thanks!  Haven't tried iireset yet, since "Rebuild" seems to do the job just fine.